# Help registering iMovie

Tags: mac, macos, video, imovie

I just transferred iMovie '08 from an older Mac to a fully updated newer one. Unfortunately, I am not the one that purchased it, so it isn't in my App purchases. Now I have a problem - or two.

I would like to get iMovie to show a timeline as opposed to what it shows right now - which is something chunkier than a timeline. So, I would either like to find a way to update iMovie or just take the existing one and change the way it displays the chosen clips.

In summary, my question is; how do I either change the view of my current iMovie, or register it to my user and then update it.

Comment: You cannot transfer ownership. Check on the App Store if your current Apple ID is eligible for the free version. If not, you'll have to buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll post in question format.

What version of mac osx do you have installed currently? How to find out in case you do not know:
`Top left corner of screen with apple icon > about this mac` You should see the name of your OS and version number in there.
What version of mac osx did you just upgrade from. Is this the same machine or a different one? What backup software or method did you use if any.

Realistically you should probably be talking to whoever bought the application and Apple if you want to transfer ownership.

Worst case scenario, iMovie is $15… also, there are other options out there that are pretty good and cheap, some even free. A post on [slant.co](http://www.slant.co/topics/2272/~free-video-editing-software) suggested [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) a hollywood approved film editor, [Hitfilm 3 Express](https://hitfilm.com/express) a video editor + compositor in one package, [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) a GNU Linux initiative which could potentially be built using macports. I found a recommendation for [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) on lifehacker on a random article about [Superior Alternatives to Boring Stock Mac Apps](http://lifehacker.com/superior-alternatives-to-boring-stock-mac-apps-5870406). Their other pick as a replacement for imovie [Screenflow 5](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screenflow-5/id917790450?mt=12) got terrible reviews (screencaster software, not dedicated video editor)

Comment: I'm not sure, I have the old computer all taken apart right now. The one I transferred to is 10.11.2. Unfortunately, the computer is one of 38 I purchased, used, on a skid. They came from UC and OU; as well as a couple of middle schools.

Comment: Asides from exploring alternatives to iMovie or speaking with Apple I don't think there's much we can do to help you. Based on my experience with Apple representatives thus far they're pretty understanding and emphatic. Best of luck!